# Creating a new node and putting object beans under it java magnolia

Tags: java, jcr, magnolia

I am working in magnolia and the backend is in java. I need to check whether a node is present in the component that I do with these steps

```
if (!MgnlContext.getJCRSession("repository").nodeExists(path)) {
                MgnlContext.getJCRSession ("repository").getRootNode().addNode("nodeName", "mgnl:content");
                }
```

now I need to put a bean (java object bean)  inside this node. for eg: as it should come as a content node under it.

Can anyone suggest any methods to do it better?

Answer (score 0):

To map any java been to content in repository, your best option in Magnolia is to use the `Node2Bean`. It allows you to map the content of your java bean/pojo to JCR Node and back. More details in [documentation](https://magnolia-cms.zoom.us/j/95405989999).

Answer (score 0):

Fixed by denoting a @Field(path = true) in the bean and set that variable in the node path which is created using created. –  MgnlContext.getJCRSession ("repository").getRootNode().addNode("nodeName", "mgnl:content"). so by doing this when i persisted the bean it went inside the node which i created .

Answer (score 0):

In order to manage nodes/properties in Magnolia you can also use these utils:

- `info.magnolia.jcr.util.NodeUtil`
- `info.magnolia.jcr.util.SessionUtil`
- `info.magnolia.jcr.util.PropertyUtil`